# Cron job scheduler to add new quartz jobs every day?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'd like to run crobjob every day on 1AM to add new Quartz.net jobs that will be run in the same day once and get deleted.

So far, i'm able to add jobs to listen to every soccer match but don't know how to add a cron job to add these job every day.

```
class LiveScheduledJobs : IScheduledJob
    {
     public IScheduler Run()
        {
            var schd = GetScheduler();
            if (!schd.IsStarted)
                schd.Start();
            string jobName = "", triggerName = "";
            using (var db = new ABCDataContext())
            {
                var fixtures = db.Fixtures;
                string group = "livematch";                
                foreach (var item in fixtures.Where(blahblah))
                {
                    jobName = "match" + item.Id;
                    triggerName = "trigger" + item.Id;                   
                    int categoryId = db.Fixture_Category_Mappings.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FixtureId == item.Id).CategoryId;
                    var seasonStage = db.Season_Stage_Mappings.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == item.SeasonStageId);
                    // Define the Job to be scheduled
                    var job = JobBuilder.Create<LiveMatchJob>()
                        .WithIdentity(jobName, group )
                        .UsingJobData("url", item.AutoUrl)
                        .UsingJobData("seasonId", seasonStage.SeasonId)
                        .UsingJobData("categoryId", categoryId)
                        .UsingJobData("stageId", seasonStage.StageId)
                        .RequestRecovery()
                        .Build();

                    DateTimeOffset startTime = new DateTime(item.Time.Year, item.Time.Month, item.Time.Day,
                                              item.Time.Hour, item.Time.Minute, item.Time.Second);


                    ITrigger triggerLive = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity(triggerName, group)
                    .StartAt(startTime)
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x =>x.WithIntervalInMinutes(2).RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

                    // Validate that the job doesn't already exists
                    if (schd.CheckExists(new JobKey(jobName, group)))
                    {
                        schd.DeleteJob(new JobKey(jobName, group));
                    }
                    var schedule = schd.ScheduleJob(job, triggerLive);
                }
            }
            return schd;

        }
```

LiveMatchJob:

```
  public class LiveMatchJob : IJob
{
    private Object thisLock = new Object();
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        JobKey jobKey = context.JobDetail.Key;
        var triggerKey = context.Trigger.Key;
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
        string url = dataMap.GetString("url");
        int seasonId = dataMap.GetInt("seasonId");
        int categoryId = dataMap.GetInt("categoryId");
        int stageId = dataMap.GetInt("stageId");

        using (var db = new ABCDataContext())
        {
            try
            {

                var fixture = db.Fixtures.FirstOrDefault(f => f.AutoUrl == url.Trim());
                if (fixture.IsComplete)
                {                        
                    context.Scheduler.DeleteJob(jobKey);  >> remove job when done
                }
                else
                {

                    context.Scheduler.PauseTrigger(triggerKey);
                    ....
                    context.Scheduler.ResumeTrigger(triggerKey);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html Explains CRON triggers pretty well. If you clarify what your trying and what is failing I am sure i can help.

Comment: these examples are for running a cron job for one ForJob("myJob", "group1"). What about having a cron job to add a bunch of tasks like above?

Comment: So in the above example, when your LiveJobMatch executes you want to add additional Jobs to your schedule? Or do you want a different Job to add LiveJobMatches?

Comment: Should I run 2 schedulers like my below answer? Thanks.

Comment: ye you can do that, however what stops you from just adding the Cron job to your existing schedule?

Answer (score 0):

I add another scheduler:

```
class CronJobScheduler : IScheduledJob
{
    public IScheduler Run()
    {
        var schd = GetScheduler();
        if (!schd.IsStarted)
            schd.Start();


        var trigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
                      .WithIdentity("cronjobTrigger", "cronGroup1")
                       .WithCronSchedule("0 0 1 1/1 * ? *")
                      .StartAt(DateTime.UtcNow)
                       .WithPriority(1)
                     .Build();


        var job = JobBuilder.Create<CronJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("cronjob", "cronGroup1")
                    .RequestRecovery()
                    .Build();

        var schedule = schd.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        return schd;

    }




    // Get an instance of the Quartz.Net scheduler
    private static IScheduler GetScheduler()
    {
        try
        {
            var properties = new NameValueCollection();
            properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "ServerScheduler";

            // set remoting expoter
            properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
            properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", "localhost", "555",
                                                                         "QuartzScheduler");

            // Get a reference to the scheduler
            var sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();//properties);
            return sf.GetScheduler();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Scheduler not available: '{0}'", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
    public void Shutdown(IScheduler schd)
    {
        schd.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

and from Cronjob, i make a call to other scheduler

```
 public class CronJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var sj = new LiveScheduledJobs();
        var schd = sj.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add an extra scheduler. Create one job that schedules the other jobs.

For example, create a JobSchedulingJob that inherits from IJob:

```
public class JobScheduling : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var schd = context.Scheduler;
        scheduleOtherJobs(scheduler);//this is where you schedule the other jobs    
    }
}
```

Then, schedule this JobSchedulingJob to run every day using a CronTrigger.